# Bootstrap 3: does form-horizontal work for radio buttons with a control-label?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This has wasted several hours of my day. Here's a very simple form, with 2 radio buttons and a label, on [bootply](http://bootply.com/102820). This works as expected on 2.3.2: 'Date Range' on the left, buttons on the right. On Bootstrap 3, everything's out, it's basically vertical instead of horizontal, the text is bold, and it's just a mess. Any ideas, short of re-doing this as a grid?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

This is the expected layout, when B2.3.2 is selected on bootply:

[image]

This is what I get when I select any B3+:

[image]

Comment: I posted the classes you're supposed to use. There was a lot of changes to the forms and the migration list is helpful but nothing is more helpful than pulling apart the examples on getbootstrap.com

Comment: Thanks - what you're saying is, I think, that the old classes which provided alignment have been dropped, and you have to align everything manually using the grid layout? I only started Bootstrap a few days ago, and this isn't at all obvious from the docs.

Comment: In the example below only the grid classes set up the control-label and the container with the second, right column. You'd use the "radio-inline" class for radios and checkbox-inline.

Comment: But surely `col-sm-` is just not the right way to do this. I don't want a responsive layout - I want a *fixed* layout, ie. the layout you get if you go to the bootply example, log on, and change from B3 to B2.3.2. In other words, a label on the left side, and two stacked radio buttons to the right of the label, with one radio button being on top of the other radio button. B3 stacks the 2 radios correctly (one top, one bottom), but leaves the label on top, not to the left, and screws up the font styling. Can anyone convince me that gridding is the answer, or fix the B3 code?

Comment: you can use col-xs and then stack them inside using the correct classes for that. See the example below. I've been using the forms on BS3 for 3 months now, this is the correct way of doing it because all form elements are 100% so you need col- but you can use the xs variety and get a fixed layout that doesn't change from breakpoint to breakpoint

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To do what you want to do, you do have to use col-* classes as all form elements are 100% width, so you have to have a  col-* to fix the width you want. You can use col-xs-* and it will be for all sizes, not responsive:

[image]

**EXAMPLE: http://bootply.com/102912**

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
 <fieldset>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Date Range</label>
   <div class="col-xs-9">
    <div class="radio">
     <label>
      <input id="inlineradio1" name="sampleinlineradio" value="option1" type="radio">
      Radio 0</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
     <label>
      <input id="inlineradio1" name="sampleinlineradio" value="option1" type="radio">
      Radio 0</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
     <label>
      <input id="inlineradio1" name="sampleinlineradio" value="option1" type="radio">
      Radio 0</label>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </fieldset>
</form>
```

If you want radios, checkboxes, or other form elements on the same line without the use of column classes, the class for the form is `.form-inline`:

**http://bootply.com/102908**

```
<form class="form-inline">
   <div class="form-group">
    <label class="radio-inline">Date Range</label>
         <label class="radio-inline">
     <input id="inlineradio1" name="sampleinlineradio" value="option1" type="radio">
     Radio 0</label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
     <input id="inlineradio2" name="sampleinlineradio" value="option2" type="radio">
     Radio 2</label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
     <input id="inlineradio3" name="sampleinlineradio" value="option3" type="radio">
     Radio 3</label>
    </div>
   <!--form-group-->
 </form>
```

Comment: Ok, you've convinced me, but I can't help thinking that simply using a table would be easier and more logical.

Answer (score 37):

I needed the same arrangement but with both horizontal and vertical radios. For Bootstrap 3.2, there is a form-horizontal that works nicely with columns.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
```

[image]

#### Full Form

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <p class="bg-warning">Note: In the Stack Snippet, you may need to click "Full Page", otherwise the container is narrow enough to cause Bootstrap to stack the labels over the fields.</p>
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Season</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <label class="radio-inline"> <input type="radio" name="season" id="seasonSummer" value="summer" checked> Summer </label>
            <label class="radio-inline"> <input type="radio" name="season" id="seasonWinter" value="winter"> Winter </label>
            <label class="radio-inline"> <input type="radio" name="season" id="seasonSpringFall" value="spring-fall" disabled> Spring-Fall </label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Clouds</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <label class="radio-inline"> <input type="radio" name="clouds" id="Clear" value="clear" checked> Clear </label>
            <label class="radio-inline"> <input type="radio" name="clouds" id="Cloudy" value="cloudy"> Cloudy </label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Load Forecast</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="radio">
                <label> <input type="radio" name="load" id="WeekdayAverage" value="weekdayaverage" checked> Weekday - Average </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label> <input type="radio" name="load" id="WeekdayPeak" value="weekdaypeak"> Weekday - Peak </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label> <input type="radio" name="load" id="Weekend" value="weekend" disabled> Weekend </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </form>
</div>
```