# Rails Bootstrap_form - Radio buttons not rendering label name in the show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, radio-button, bootstrap-form-helper

I have a form built with the bootstrap_form gem for ruby. within the form I have some radio buttons. the form renders perfectly with the correct labeling in the edit page of the form, however once I save the form and go to the "show" page to see the results, the inputs for the radio buttons are only showing the value of the radio button (which are numbers) and not the custom label name I have assigned. How can I make the custom label appear instead of the value in the show page?

Here is my code:

_form.html.erb:

```
  <%= f.form_group :gender, label: { text: "Gender" } do %>
    <%= f.radio_button :gender, 0, label: "Female", checked: true, inline: true  %>
    <%= f.radio_button :gender, 1, label: "Male", inline: true  %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.form_group :nationality, label: { text: "Nationality" } do %>
    <%= f.radio_button :nationality, 0, label: "Kuwaiti", checked: true, inline: true  %>
    <%= f.radio_button :nationality, 1, label: "Non-Kuwaiti", inline: true  %>
  <% end %>
```

show.html.erb

```
    <p><strong>Full Name:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= @profile.name %></p>
    <p><strong>Civil ID no:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= @profile.civil %></p>
    <p><strong>Gender:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= @profile.gender %></p>
    <p><strong>Nationality:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= @profile.nationality %></p>
    <p><strong>Mobile no:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= @profile.mobile %></p>
    <p><strong>Personal Email:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= @profile.personal_email %></p>
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

**Update:-**

New form code:-

```
<%= f.form_group :gender, label: { text: "Gender" } do %>
    <%= f.radio_button :gender, 1  %>
    <%= f.label 'Female', inline: true, checked: true  %>
    <%= f.radio_button :gender, 0  %>
    <%= f.label 'Male', inline: true  %>
  <% end %>
```

Tried this suggestion but still getting the same problem, only the the radio buttons are no longer in line and have incorrect formatting.

Comment: What version of Rails are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You need a lookup table

You have saved numeric values that correspond to the radio button. So, when you display the variable in the show.htm.erb it is showing the numeric values retrieved from the database record. This makes sense. But you need the string associated with the number, which requires a lookup table

**Creating labels in the form does not create custom labels for your field.** To create custom field labels, you would need to setup i18n localizations for your activerecord models, which is a good solution, but also one that will take some time and learning curve.

Creating a hash-based lookup table.

### Active Hash gem

You could write your own lookup helper or use this [gem](https://github.com/zilkey/active_hash) which simplifies implementing hash-based lookup tables.

## **Example**

```
# in app/models/person.rb
class Gender < ActiveHash::Base
  self.data = [
    {:id => 0, :gender => "Female"},
    {:id => 1, :gender => "Male"}
  ]
end
```

From their spec

> We wrote ActiveHash so that we could use simple, in-memory, ActiveRecord-like data structures that play well with Rails forms...

**Build error in gem (Update)**

I just checked an it seems their build has an error. Probably best to avoid for now.

---

### Using view helpers to translate boolean values to strings (Added)

You could implement helpers your /helpers/profile_helper.rb. I call them "lookups," but that is probably not standard.

For each of the boolean you need to translate to strings create a helper

```
#profile_helper.rb  
# Each of your booleans
def gender_to_s(value)
    value ? "Male" : "Female"
end

def nationality_to_s(value)
    value ? "Kuwaiti" : "Non-Kuwaiti"
end


# Generic true/false conversion
def boolean_to_s(value)
    value ? "Yes" : "No"
end
```

Note: I would name the helpers consistently to match the field name, so in your view it is very obvious which "to_s" to invoke.

**In your view**

```
<p><strong>Gender:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= gender_to_s(@profile.gender)  %></p>
```

Note: If you wanted a single view helper, this could be implemented in application_helper.rb and include a passed parameter "type" as a switch control, but I think the most straightforward solution is to create a view helper for each field.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried adding the active Hash gem and followed the steps provided but it doesn't seem to do anything. Im not sure what im doing wrong. would you be able to guide me through the process of implementing it? I am new to rails (and programming in general) so alot of this is completely new to me. Anyway thanks for the help!

Comment: If the gem isn't working out of the box, then I suggest creating your own lookup helpers. And that might also make it easier in the future if you want to use i18n internationalization on your strings. I'll update the last section in my answer with this info.

Comment: It seems like the gem is failing build. I hope the view helper section I added solves your problem. Let me know.

Comment: Hey sorry for the late response. I just implemented your suggestion to use helpers and it seems to work, with one minor issue: the result of the radio button on the show page seems to be stuck on one option no matter what input I choose. for example if I choose "Female" in the form im still getting "Male". Do you know what the issue might be?

Comment: Nevermind I just figured out the problem, I had my data type set to integer rather than boolean. Your solution works perfectly, thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Glad to hear this. Good luck with your app.

Answer (score 0):

You want a separate tag for the labels. Instead of:

```
<%= f.radio_button :gender, 1, label: "Male", inline: true  %>
```

You need:

```
<%= f.radio_button :gender, 1  %>
<%= f.label 'Male, inline: true  %>
```

Might also be worth looking at this answer: [Bootstrap 3: does form-horizontal work for radio buttons with a control-label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819010/bootstrap-3-does-form-horizontal-work-for-radio-buttons-with-a-control-label)

It doesn't use the form label helper, but it looks like it does what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried the code you suggested but it doesnt seem to work. I posted an update to my question with the new code based on your suggestion if you dont mind checking it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK one more approach so that you have a full set to choose from.  In Rails 4.1, enum data types were implemented in ActiveRecord as described in section 2.5 of the [release notes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html).  If you are running Rails 4.1+, you can take advantage of this new feature.

Essentially, you will need to write migrations to change your boolean and other data types to enum.  For instance, for the gender example, rather than having gender of 0 signify female and 1 signify male, and maintain a mapping for that, you could simply have:

```
enum gender: [:female, :male]
```

and likewise for your other attributes.

This should ultimately be easier to maintain and will help keep your application code as transparent as possible.

Comment: Hello, I have tried to implement the method you suggested however it is not working correctly. I am getting an error: ArgumentError in ProfilesController#update
'1' is not a valid gender. the error appears whenever I try to update the form. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are you running Rails 4.1+?  Can you update your OP with relevant snippets from your schema, model and controller code (or start a new question and respond here with a link to it).

Answer (score 0):

```
 <label><%= form.radio_button :gender, 1, hide_label: true, inline: true%>Female</label>
 <label><%= form.radio_button :gender, 0, hide_label: true, inline: true%>Male</label>
```

worked for me Bootstrap 4.1